# Iterative use of fsolve

Tags: matlab

i must calculate an `F(x,k)=0` function 200 times.
Each time with a different k parameter value.
F is a nonlinear function, so i'm trying to use fsolve.

I'm not able to pass the k parameter value to the anonymous function used for the fsolve call.

The code i use is the following :

```
[x,fval,exitflag,output,jacobian] = fsolve(@(x)nucom,x0,options)
```

where ''nucom'' is the function F that must be zero.

How do i pass k?
Using `@(x,k)` syntax some error incomes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming nucom takes `k` as an argument, your syntax should be something like:

```
xsolved=zeros(1,200);
for k=1:200
    [x,fval,exitflag,output,jacobian]=fsolve(@(x)nucom(x,k),x0,options);
    xsolved(k)=x;
end
```

Comment: <stopping criteria details>
Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.  What if my function file has k^(0.6)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `@(x) nucom(x,k)`.